# Flutter app builds successfully on iOS but "flutter build" command returns null warnings and ':flutter_paystack:compileReleaseKotlin' error

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-3.0

My flutter application out of the blue starts to show SchedulerBinding null warnings and fails to build unless I take out the following packages

:flutter_paystack: ^1.0.5+1
:qr_code_scanner: ^0.6.1

I have not uploaded project to Flutter v3 and I use the flag "--no-sound-null-safety" with my build command. I haven't made any obvious change since the last successful build and I am able to build successfully on iOS

> m@Ms-MacBook-Pro axterik % fvm flutter build apk --release --no-sound-null-safety

````
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/another_flushbar-1.10.28/lib/flushbar.dart:350:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/2.10.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
    SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(
                     ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pinput-1.2.0/lib/pin_put/pin_put_state.dart:49:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/2.10.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
                   ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pinput-1.2.0/lib/pin_put/pin_put_state.dart:73:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/2.10.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
                   ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_code_scanner-0.6.1/lib/src/qr_code_scanner.dart:68:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/2.10.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(_observer);
                   ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/qr_code_scanner-0.6.1/lib/src/qr_code_scanner.dart:86:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/2.10.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(_observer);
                   ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/printing-5.6.5/lib/src/preview/pdf_preview.dart:169:35: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/2.10.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    final locale = WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.locale;
                                  ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/printing-5.6.5/lib/src/preview/pdf_preview.dart:214:37: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/2.10.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
      final locale = WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.locale;
                                    ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker-20.1.51/lib/src/date_picker/date_picker.dart:8063:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/2.10.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
    SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                     ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker-20.1.51/lib/src/date_picker/date_picker.dart:9832:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/2.10.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
    SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                     ^
../../../.pub-cache/git/syncfusion_flutter_charts-670dbef08021a017d34d6c8282b43d7977dc2618/lib/src/chart/base/chart_base.dart:1795:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/2.10.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
        SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                         ^
../../../.pub-cache/git/syncfusion_flutter_charts-670dbef08021a017d34d6c8282b43d7977dc2618/lib/src/chart/base/chart_base.dart:1804:28: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/2.10.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
          SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _refresh());
                           ^
../../../.pub-cache/git/syncfusion_flutter_charts-670dbef08021a017d34d6c8282b43d7977dc2618/lib/src/circular_chart/base/circular_base.dart:948:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/2.10.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
        SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                         ^
../../../.pub-cache/git/syncfusion_flutter_charts-670dbef08021a017d34d6c8282b43d7977dc2618/lib/src/circular_chart/base/circular_base.dart:962:28: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/2.10.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
          SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _refresh());
                           ^
../../../.pub-cache/git/syncfusion_flutter_charts-670dbef08021a017d34d6c8282b43d7977dc2618/lib/src/funnel_chart/base/funnel_base.dart:720:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/2.10.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
        SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                         ^
../../../.pub-cache/git/syncfusion_flutter_charts-670dbef08021a017d34d6c8282b43d7977dc2618/lib/src/funnel_chart/base/funnel_base.dart:732:28: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/2.10.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
          SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _refresh());
                           ^
../../../.pub-cache/git/syncfusion_flutter_charts-670dbef08021a017d34d6c8282b43d7977dc2618/lib/src/pyramid_chart/base/pyramid_base.dart:714:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/2.10.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
        SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                         ^
../../../.pub-cache/git/syncfusion_flutter_charts-670dbef08021a017d34d6c8282b43d7977dc2618/lib/src/pyramid_chart/base/pyramid_base.dart:725:28: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/2.10.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
          SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _refresh());
                           ^
../../../.pub-cache/git/searchfield-95cf2efd54578879a9671714caed7f7aeb7d014a/lib/src/searchfield.dart:318:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/2.10.0/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^
e: /Users/m/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_paystack-1.0.5+1/android/src/main/kotlin/co/paystack/flutterpaystack/FlutterPaystackPlugin.kt: (48, 62): Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected
e: /Users/m/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_paystack-1.0.5+1/android/src/main/kotlin/co/paystack/flutterpaystack/MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt: (19, 37): Type mismatch: inferred type is BinaryMessenger? but BinaryMessenger was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_paystack:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 3s```



Flutter doctor 

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.13.0-0.0.pre.166, on macOS 12.2.1 21D62 darwin-x64, locale en-NG)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[!] Android Studio
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.2.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.68.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.


PS: I have tried flutter clean, Invalidate caches, delete pod file..
````

Answer (score -1):

try to check if the package is resolvable

flutter pub outdated

flutter pub upgrade

Comment: I tried that, sadly, it made no difference